# Create alias for a specific command in cmd

Tags: cmd, alias

Is there anyway to create an alias to `cd PATH` command in cmd?

For example, instead of typing `cd C:\John\Pictures` I'd like to type just `pictures` in cmd and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it should simply take me to `C:\John\Pictures`.

Is that possible and how?

Comment: Take a look at [`doskey`](http://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html) and its *macro* feature...

Comment: As an aside, you might want to do `cd /d` instead of just `cd`.

Comment: Thanks guys, exactly as you said. Just one mroe thing, in order to make it work persistently, you need to add /K file_path to Target in cmd.exe properties, example: %windir%\system32\cmd.exe /K C:\use-macros.cmd. use-macros.cmd file should include the command: doskey /macrofile=macinit, which cmd.exe will run on startup and that command simply allows you to use the stored macros.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will need to use the [`doskey` command](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html) which creates aliases. For example:

```bat
doskey note = "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
note
```

creates a macro to open Notepad, then calls it. The [macro](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-macros.html) name (`note` in the above example) must be valid (e.g. no spaces are allowed, may begin with an underscore).

You can also use parameters:

```bat
doskey note = "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" $1
note "C:\Users\....\textfile.txt"
```

---

By default, `doskey` macros are only saved for the current session. You can work around this limitation in two ways:

1. Save the macros in a text file, [then load them each time you need them](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html):

   > A command like:
   >
   > ```bat
   > doskey /macros > %TEMP%\doskey-macros.txt
   > ```
   >
   > Will save all the current macro definitions into a text file.
   >
   > ---
   >
   > Then to restore all the macros at a later date:
   >
   > ```bat
   > doskey /macrofile=%TEMP%\doskey-macros.txt
   > ```
2. After saving the macros in a text file as shown above, instead of loading them every time, run:

   ```bat
   reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun /d "doskey /macrofile=\"%TEMP%\doskey-macros.txt\"" /f
   ```

   so that the macros are set each time you open the cmd.

   See [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1134468) for more information.

---

Note: You **cannot** use command aliases in a batch file.

Answer (score 20):

Here is an alternative for Windows 10:

**1. Create a file called `init.cmd` and save it to your user folder**

*C:\Users\YourName\init.cmd*

```
@echo off
doskey c=cls
doskey d=cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
doskey e=explorer $*
doskey jp=cd C:\John\Pictures
doskey l=dir /a $*
```

**2. Register it to be applied automatically whenever `cmd.exe` is executed**

*In the Command Prompt, run:*

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%"USERPROFILE"%\init.cmd" /f
```

**3. Restart the Command Prompt**

Now close/open the Command Prompt and the aliases will be available.

To unregister, run:

```
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. However, a quick glance at your delete command suggests that it will get rid of ALL autoruns rather than limiting the deletion to a specific file. Because if I have more than one command file configured to be autorun when CMD launches, then I lose that too.

Comment: @EskayAmadeus Fair, thanks. I will test with multiple commands and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: it doesn't work, and your cuotes are placed wrongly on item 2.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:
Open Notepad in admin mode
go to C:\Windows\System32
New file
Contents: `dir %1`
Save it here as `ls.bat`
This will give you `ls`

Same way, `git status %1` saved as gs.bat would give you `gs` instead of having to type out `git status` all the time.
In the newer releases of windows there are many different ways to do this and they are (hopefully) getting simpler and easier, but this method will take care of commands you would type lots of times every day. Just make sure to keep a backup of the files you've created, somewhere outside System32, because some windows updates will wipe them out.