# how to create a cmd shortcut to a project directory

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt, shortcut

I want to be able to open cmd and the do `:cd project` and this will put be in this directory>

> `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Projects\Random_shi\NWT`

I know its possible because I saw someone in a youtube video do it once but I couldn't find anything online.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54866820/create-alias-for-a-specific-command-in-cmd#54872621

This is if you are using ye olde CMD.exe ...

Answer (score 0):

Using a DOSKEY shortcut works great

```
doskey shortcut=cd /d PATH
```

replace shortcut with whatever you want to use to navigate to your folder and PATH with the path to your directory

Example

```
doskey NWT=cd /d C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Projects\Random_shi\NWT
```

Then all you have to do is call

```
C:\Users\USER>NWT
```